# Unable to run Android app after creating new AVD

Tags: java, android, eclipse, illegalargumentexception, runtimeexception

I created a new AVD and my app doesn't seem to run anymore. Here is the stacktrace, not sure how to diagnose.

```
04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.stocktwits.activity/org.stocktwits.activity.Main}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no char field 'exponential'
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no char field 'exponential'
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.EmulatedFields.put(EmulatedFields.java:459)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.EmulatedFieldsForDumping.put(EmulatedFieldsForDumping.java:83)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.writeObject(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:591)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1219)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1062)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1008)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.text.DecimalFormat.writeObject(DecimalFormat.java:1215)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1219)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1143)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:413)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1241)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:651)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1219)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at org.stocktwits.activity.Main.serializeQuotes(Main.java:701)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at org.stocktwits.activity.Main.populateDefaultQuotes(Main.java:533)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at org.stocktwits.activity.Main.onStart(Main.java:481)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3791)
    04-25 10:11:27.186: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(742):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1620)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting a gingerbread emulator? See this post: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14495

You will need to replace your `DecimalFormatSymbols` code